# About c# lists send it or return it?

Tags: c#, list

I have one question. I have to do a method that fills a List < object > from a sql database. My question is:

It's better to do this:

```
List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
listProducts = loadProducts();

//this code is in other class
public List<Product> loadProducts()
{
    List<Product > listProduct = new List<Product> ();
    //code        
    return listProduct
}
```

Or it's better this:

```
List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
listProducts = loadProducts(listProducts);

//this code is in other class
public List<Product> loadProducts(List<Product> listProduct)
{
    //Code        
    return listProduct
}
```

Sorry if it's a noob question but both of two works but I don't know which is more improved.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your first method, with `List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();` you are creating a new empty list for nothing (the next line assigns a new list instance). just do `List<Product> listProducts = loadProducts(listProducts);`

Comment: I try to minimize side-effects because I find it leads to less confusing code. Creating objects is *cheap* on modern hardware -- don't be afraid of it. I avoid the second approach and that idiom does not appear in my code. (The one exception I can remember is when using DataTables, but that was a very special and noted situation.) If you *do* modify the List passed in, *please have a void return type* so the caller is "aware" that the operation utilizes a side-effect. (Consider `List.Add` as a method that follows that rule.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for this

```
List<Product> listProducts = loadProducts();

//this code is in other class
public List<Product> loadProducts()
{
    List<Product > listProduct = new List<Product> ();
    //code        
    return listProduct
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Neither, really.

You should just go like so:

```
 List<Product> listProducts = loadProducts();
```

Option 1 makes a new list only to overwrite it later. Option 2 needlessly passes a list to the method, which will just send it back out modified.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to return it.  Unless there is something with the contents of the list when you send it, I don't really see a reason to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: ok thanks, I thought that, but the second code ( pass list as a parameter ) I've copied from a old source I have, and now I think that it's incorrect, but if one day I made it, maybe was for something ( or maybe was bad ) Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option is much better. It has clear meaning and no side effects.

Your second option will both return the list as well as fill the list that was passed to it. I would consider the filling of the list I pass to be a side effect which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the first approach.

It seems somewhat pointless to pass the method a list which will then be populated and returned.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is better.  The second option isn't bad if you make it a void function and put the list as a reference parameter, but option one is still better because there is nothing in the original list needed for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that in any case you would like to pass an existing list (with stuff already there) to be incremented I like the first option since it's more readable